# How am I misusing Java's MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to write a virtual file class in Java. I think snippets of my code below are simple enough to see the problem. Basically I have to force my buffer to rewind() in weird places for my example to work (marked as calls to hugeHack() below). I am misunderstanding the use of seeks on the underlying channel and positioning within the buffer. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty sure it is some simple misunderstanding. I'm hoping to avoid the hugeHack() because my class is a random access data structure and you can't tell what order you'll read and write and my test is very predictable and unrealistic in how it will be used.

Here are excerpts of my class:

```
public class FileStorageFloat64<U extends DoubleCoder & Allocatable<U>>
    implements IndexedDataSource<U>, Allocatable<FileStorageFloat64<U>>
{
    private final long numElements;
    private final U type;
    private final double[] tmpArray;
    private final long byteCount;
    private final File file;
    private final RandomAccessFile raf;
    private final FileChannel channel;
    private final MappedByteBuffer buffer;

    public FileStorageFloat64(long numElements, U type) {
        this.numElements = numElements;
        this.type = type.allocate();
        this.tmpArray = new double[type.doubleCount()];
        this.byteCount = numElements * type.doubleCount() * 8;
        try {
            this.file = File.createTempFile("Storage", ".storage");
            this.file.deleteOnExit();
            this.raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            this.channel = raf.getChannel();
            this.buffer = this.channel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, this.byteCount);
            for (long i = 0; i < this.byteCount; i++) {
                this.buffer.put((byte)0);
            }
            this.buffer.rewind();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void set(long index, U value) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= numElements)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("storage index out of bounds");
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                value.toDoubleArray(this.tmpArray, 0);
                long pos = index * this.type.doubleCount() * 8;
                this.channel.position(pos);
                for (int i = 0; i < this.tmpArray.length; i++) {
                    this.buffer.putDouble(this.tmpArray[i]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void get(long index, U value) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.numElements)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("storage index out of bounds");
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                long pos = index * this.type.doubleCount() * 8;
                this.channel.position(pos);
                for (int i = 0; i < this.tmpArray.length; i++) {
                    this.tmpArray[i] = this.buffer.getDouble();
                }
                value.fromDoubleArray(this.tmpArray, 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void hugeHack() {
        this.buffer.rewind();
    }
```

And here is a test method:

```
    public void run() {

        final int SIZE = 40;

        ComplexFloat64Member v = new ComplexFloat64Member();

        FileStorageFloat64<ComplexFloat64Member> store = new FileStorageFloat64<ComplexFloat64Member>(SIZE, new ComplexFloat64Member());

        assertEquals(SIZE, store.size());

        for (long i = 0; i < store.size(); i++) {
            v.setR(i);
            v.setI(i+1);
            store.set(i, v);
        }

        store.hugeHack();

        for (long i = 0; i < store.size(); i++) {
            store.get(i, v);
            assertEquals(i, v.r(), 0);
            assertEquals(i+1, v.i(), 0);
        }

        store.hugeHack();

        FileStorageFloat64<ComplexFloat64Member> dup = store.duplicate(); // not shown above

        dup.hugeHack();

        assertEquals(store.size(), dup.size());

        for (long i = 0; i < dup.size(); i++) {
            dup.get(i, v);
            assertEquals(i, v.r(), 0);
            assertEquals(i+1, v.i(), 0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The seeks have no effect. The buffer covers the entire file. You just have to position yourself within the buffer. Bit if the file didn't already exist it will be zero length when you create it here, which can't be what you want.

Comment: I don't understand about `rewind()`. You are calling `position()` every time before you get or put something, which is sufficient. What happens if you don't rewind?

Comment: I get buffer underflows or buffer overflows. The constructor for the MappedByteBuffer takes long values. It could represent something huge that would not fit in ram. I was of the opinion the MappedByteBuffer is a window on a big file. Am I misunderstanding here? I can't use set pos on the buffer because it only takes int params and I need longs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I futzed all yesterday and found a solution that uses ByteBuffer; just not MappedByteBuffer. It is 10 to 100 times faster than my old RandomAccessFile approach. I may call this good enough for now.

```
public class FileStorageFloat64<U extends DoubleCoder & Allocatable<U>>
    implements IndexedDataSource<U>, Allocatable<FileStorageFloat64<U>>
{
    private final long numElements;
    private final U type;
    private final double[] tmpArray;
    private final int bufSize;
    private final File file;
    private final RandomAccessFile raf;
    private final FileChannel channel;
    private final ByteBuffer buffer;

    /**
     * 
     * @param numElements
     * @param type
     */
    public FileStorageFloat64(long numElements, U type) {
        this.numElements = numElements;
        this.type = type.allocate();
        this.tmpArray = new double[type.doubleCount()];
        this.bufSize = type.doubleCount() * 8;
        try {
            this.file = File.createTempFile("Storage", ".storage");
            this.file.deleteOnExit();
            this.raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            this.channel = raf.getChannel();
            // make a one element buffer
            this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufSize);
            // fill the buffer with zeroes
            for (int i = 0; i < type.doubleCount(); i++) {
                buffer.putDouble(0);
            }
            // write zeroes to the file over and over
            channel.position(0);
            for (long i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
                channel.write(buffer);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void set(long index, U value) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.numElements)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("storage index out of bounds");
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                value.toDoubleArray(this.tmpArray, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < this.tmpArray.length; i++) {
                    this.buffer.putDouble(i*8, this.tmpArray[i]);
                }
                this.buffer.rewind();
                long pos = index * this.bufSize;
                this.channel.position(pos);
                this.channel.write(this.buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void get(long index, U value) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.numElements)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("storage index out of bounds");
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                buffer.rewind();
                long pos = index * bufSize;
                this.channel.position(pos);
                this.channel.read(this.buffer);
                for (int i = 0; i < this.tmpArray.length; i++) {
                    this.tmpArray[i] = this.buffer.getDouble(i*8);
                }
                value.fromDoubleArray(this.tmpArray, 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```